# Is it possible to stream insert into Couchbase a large file

Tags: scala, rx-java, couchbase, akka-stream

Is it possible to stream insert a binary file into couchbase? Im using a wrapper around RXJava to stream read is it also possible stream write?

Comment: What do you mean by "large"? Couchbase documents are 20mb maximum in size, and therefore are not particularly well-suited for storing files.

Comment: Do you mean binary files or binary data? You can use rxJava for inserts almost the same way you use it for gets.

Comment: Im currently trying to implement this solution using akka-streams and scala: http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/storing-blobs-in-couchbase-for-content-management

I mean, binary files. I do use rxJava with scala akka-streams wrapper but as I understand it, streaming happens when resulting rows/docs are more than one and rows/docs themselves are not chunked using rxJava